# Microsoft Azure wordpress install is not appearing

Tags: wordpress, azure, installation

I have set up a second wordpress web app in Microsoft Azure however when i go to the url no wordpress install wizard is appearing. Not sure if this is because i am on a free account that can be used by students or if i have done something wrong? My first web app is still working. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't have to do with anything about being a student. There is a free tier, and you can make multiple free tiered sites.

You didn't say what appears when you go to the URL though, so it could be any number of errors. Here is a checklist of what I'd go through:

- Make sure you are going to the correct new URL
- Can you FTP into the new web app, and verify there is WordPress code there? If not, something weird happened in the set up process! Delete the web app and try again, or simply upload WordPress yourself! Can get the files from WordPress.org and upload yourself using FTP
- If WordPress code is there... What appears when you go to the URL? If it's an error message, something might have messed up in the install. You can always delete it and remake it to start again. Without knowing the error message, I can't really give more specific advice.
- As a side note, did you create a new ClearDB MySQL database? Can you confirm there is a second database on your ClearDB account? If not, that could easily be the problem.

Sorry to give vague answers, but without more specifics to go on not many more details I can give. Except confirm that yes, you should be able to make multiple WordPress sites, so either something has gone wrong or you did something wrong.

Comment: Hi, it is actually a blank screen appearing currently. It is just completely white, if that helps you. I will look into the database idea. Thanks